# How to fix 'failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client'

Tags: nginx

Nginx could not read files when having multiple mount points that have different sector size when using directio.

We have servers which mounts different hard drives under the root folder of Nginx. All our old disks have a sector size of 512 and when we replaced a disk suddenly Nginx could not read files from that disk.

Nothing seemed wrong on the server, we could list/read files without problem, but Nginx could not. Showing failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client in error_log.

```
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
[crit] pread() "/str/.../dsf13at.mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client
```

**Hard drive information**

Hard drives with 512

```
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

New hard drive with 4096

```
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Nginx uses a directio_alignment of 512 but that does not seem to work when hard drives have Sector size 4096.

Setting **directio_alignment** to 4k solves the problem and Nginx now can read from drives with both 512 and 4096 sector.

**Nginx config:**

```
aio threads;
aio_write on;
directio 8M;
directio_alignment 4k;
```

Comment: in what config do these `aio` options go ? it complains when I restart nginx, `aio not allowed here`

Comment: @adrianTNT all those options goes into a location block

Comment: @krishna if you use open_file_cache you can try to turn that off, maybe that helps

Comment: @stjernstrom , no I am not using open_file_cache at all....

Comment: Whats the sector size of your disk?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issu on nginx 1.22.1 / Debian 12.

I just turned off sendfile and it worked:

```
#sendfile on;
sendfile off;
```